# Android Studio could not find method compile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I try and build this happens can you please help?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see the **NOTE** there:

```
//NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong 
//in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Put it under the dependencies on the file **build.gradle (Module: app)**. 
You can see it on the left side panel.

Comment: when I do that I get the error Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: Place the dependencie in your module build.gradle file and make sure the repository contains the library

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grvrk.png

Comment: When I place the dependencies in the module build.gradle file and keep the repository containing the library I get Error:resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.jessicathornsby.fingerprintauthentication:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.

Comment: Thanks for all your help up to now

Comment: Nope not that screenshot, that's your screenshot on your post. There's another build.gradle file that you can see on the left panel under Gradle Scripts. Please check also the links as this question is already solved.

Comment: I have looked at the other answers and still do not understand what I need to put into my code.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mFES.png

Comment: Your error there is not related to your problem, it has something to do with your styles.xml.